# How can I access shared prefs values directly from xml attributes?

Tags: java, xml, attributes, sharedpreferences

I want to access my stored shared preferences values, but I want it directly accessed from attributes like I want to set a color:

```
android:textColor="@prefs/..."
```

Or if there's any other way I'll be glad to know it

Comment: I am afraid you will have to access it from Java code because you also have to choose from which SharedPreferences file it will be loaded.